# How to calculate and display average scores of students

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How can I calculate and display the average score of a student?

Here is my database table https://i.stack.imgur.com/edMKs.jpg

**Primary_model**

```
$average = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(tot_score) AS avgscore FROM scores_primary");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($average)){
echo $row['avgscore'];
}
```

**Controller**

```
$this->load->view('student/view',$data);
```

**View**

`<span><b>AVERAGE RESULT:</b><?php echo $row['avgscore']; ?></span>`

The average score doesn't display. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing it in the right way if you want average you can better create a function within the controller as shown below

```php
function calculateaverage(){
    $query = $this->db->select('AVG(totalscore) as average_score')->from('score')->get();
    return $query->row()->average_score;
}
```

and then you can call it

```php
function index(){
    $data['avg'] = $this->calculateaverage();
    $this->load->view('your-page', $data);
}
```

and then you can echo it in your-page

```php
<span><b>AVERAGE RESULT:</b><?php echo $avg; ?></span>
```

if you want avg of a specific student then you can pass student_id to the function

```php
function calculateaverage($student_id){
    $query = $this->db->select('AVG(totalscore) as  average_score')->from('score')->where('student_id', $student_id)->get();
    return $query->row()->average_score;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for some unknown reason this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: please check column name and update with your column names as in my code I have used dummy names

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

## Student Controller

```
 //  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT AVG(tot_score) FROM scores_primary WHERE student_id = ?');

         $sql = "SELECT AVG(tot_score) as average_score FROM scores_primary WHERE student_id = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($student['id']));

        $data['average_score'] = $query->result()[0]->average_score;
```

## View

```
<span><b>AVERAGE RESULT:<?php echo $average_score; ?></b></span>
```